# Sometimes pip updates but sometimes it doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I installed ActiveState Python 3.4 on a lot of servers.

To bring `pip` up to date, I'm running this command on each server:

```
"C:\Python34\python.exe" -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Some of the time, it upgrades to pip version 10.0.1:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=717cdffb2833be8409433a93746744b59505f42146e8d37de6c62b430e25d6d7
Installing collected packages: pip   
Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
    Uninstalling pip:
      Successfully uninstalled pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...
```

But, some of the time it doesn't upgrade at all and it keeps pip at version 1.5.6:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Why is it behaving differently on different servers? Is there a way to force the upgrade to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what happened. On some of the servers, when I tried to update `pip` the first time, there was an error in the middle of the process. And the folder `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1.dist-info` was created, even though the install hadn't finished. If I remove that folder and then run the upgrade, it works fine.